# Extend View and Dataset of new column. Giv empty columns only new columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, dataset, dataset-designer

I have problem with new columns in datagrid. I have many columns but I need to add 3 more.

In SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, I design the view and add more columns that exist in the ViewTable "V_FKD".

In VS2008 DataSet Designer. I add fine columns to DataSet table  "V_FKDD" and in DataSet TableAdapter "V_FKDD_TableAdapter" extend all query.

The query works fine in Management Studio.

I add 3 new column to DataGridView to which it is assigned BindingSource to which it's is assigned DataSet.

And all columns in row have data but my new columns are always empty (I check this in DB I have many rows).

Please tell me why? How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! Program have other query (`SqlCommand`) in control `BackgroundWorker`